# Declaring unordered_set with free functions for user-defined hash and comparison

Tags: c++, c++11

This code compiles fine with g++ 4.4 and '-std=c++0x'.

```
#include <unordered_set>

namespace
{

size_t IntHash ( int i )
{
    return i;
}

bool IntComp ( int i, int j )
{
    return i == j;
}

}

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    typedef std::pointer_to_unary_function<int, size_t> CustomHash;
    typedef std::pointer_to_binary_function<int, int, bool>
        CustomComp;

    typedef std::unordered_set<int, CustomHash, CustomComp> DeprecatedSet;

    DeprecatedSet deprecatedSet ( 10, std::ptr_fun ( IntHash ), std::ptr_fun ( IntComp ) );

    deprecatedSet.insert ( 5 );
    deprecatedSet.insert ( 10 );
}
```

Say, however, I didn't want to use the deprecated std::pointer_to_unary_function and std::ptr_fun, but still use the free functions:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>

namespace
{

size_t IntHash ( int i )
{
    return i;
}

bool IntComp ( int i, int j )
{
    return i == j;
}

}

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    typedef std::unordered_set<int /*, UserDefinedHash?, UserDefinedComparison? */> NewSet;

    NewSet newSet (
        10,
        std::bind ( IntHash, std::placeholders::_1 ),
        std::bind ( IntComp, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ) );

    newSet.insert ( 5 );
    newSet.insert ( 10 );
}
```

This doesn't compile, I assume because I'm not sure what to put in for **UserDefinedHash** and **UserDefinedComparison**.

It doesn't look like std::bind has a member type defining the type of the **bind** object itself.

I'm aware that there's other ways to define custom hash functions and comparisons, just curious if free/class functions can be used without deprecated standard library types and functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
std::unordered_set<int, size_t(*)(int), bool(*)(int, int)> my_set;
my_set s( 10, &IntHash, &IntComp );
```

And in order to use `std::bind`, you can use `decltype` or `std::function`

Comment: +1 for not adding the unnecessary overhead of `std::function` and `std::bind`.

Comment: I'd rather use a lambda than `std::bind` here, since you don't need the generic nature of `bind` and it might just be more efficient aswell.

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` is the replacement for `std::pointer_to_unary_function`, etc.:

```
typedef std::unordered_set<int, 
                std::function<size_t(int)>,
                std::function<bool(int,int)>> NewSet;
```

All those functors have been deprecated by `std::function`.
(Although as mentioned in the comments, etc. regular function pointers would be preferable here because `std::function` is intended for storing any type of callable entity).

Answer (score 1):

A bind object can be stored in `std::function`:

```
typedef std::unordered_set<int,
    std::function<size_t(int)>, std::function<bool(int, int)>> NewSet;

NewSet newSet (
    10,
    std::bind ( IntHash, std::placeholders::_1 ),
    std::bind ( IntComp, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ) );
```

Comment: Eh, why the heck `bind` them first? Normal function pointers can be stored just as well. Also, I really don't see why you would want `std::function` at all here, since OP very specifically only wants to use those function pointers, and `std::function` is for generically storing any kind of callable entity.